# Command line option to remove summary information from ping

Tags: linux, centos7, ping

I am currently setting up a script to measure the latency of my home internet connection, as there has been some reported issues from an external service which currently does this. The external service seems to give different results whether the IP address is used directly or if a DNS address which points to the same IP address is used.

One will randomly (and both have done this) stop connecting for seemingly no reason while the other continues to return results.

I am currently writing my own script to do the same and see if it is a problem with their software (which admittedly they think it might be) or if it is my connection being weird.

I am in London, in the UK, with a 1Gig down and 50mbps up, because yeah, that's the best available in my area.

So far I have

```
ping -D -c 55 [insert ip or dns address] >> latency-[ip or dns].log
ping -D -c 55 [insert ip or dns address] >> latency-[ip or dns].log
```

inside an .sh file on a Linux (CentOS v7) VPS which I use for other things.

But the output looks like this

```
PING [ip or dns] ([ip]) 56(84) bytes of data.
[1611310205.654229] 64 bytes from [reverse-dns] ([ip]): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=18.8 ms

--- [ip or dns] ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9014ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.268/11.192/18.883/2.943 ms
```

Is there a way to remove the summary and first line, as I'd rather have it setup to just have a list of the results, if that makes sense. (and I have read the man-page, but can't find it)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the log files and remove the summary lines with awk:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { next } /^$/ { exit }1' latency-[ip or dns].log
```

Where the record number is one (first line) skip to the next line. When a line is a blank line (just before the end summary), exit. In all other cases, print the lines (1)